# Shell script to compare two specific rows in a single CSV file

Tags: shell

I am trying to learn shell script. I have a single CSV file, which is in bellow format:

```
Time, value1, value2, value3
12-17 17:47:55.380,1,2,9
12-17 17:48:55.380,8,4,9
12-17 17:49:55.380,1,2,9
12-17 17:50:55.380,8,4,9
```

I am looking for csv output something like bellow:

```
0,0,0,0
1,7,2,0
1,-7,-2,0
1,7,2,0
```

Till now I have written code:

```
First_value=ps -ef |awk "NR==1{print ;exit}" try.csv Second_value=ps -ef |awk "NR==2{print ;exit}" try.csv  echo diff = $Second_value - $First_value
```

But I am getting error like:

> read.sh: 14: read.sh: 12-17:not found.

Following are my queries:

- I am not able to put this in loop and get the output. I would like to
  know, how i can write the result back to same csv file,but at
  particular row and column.

Comment: difference between what rows exactly?

Comment: What's expected output and what have you tried?

Comment: Please share your code that you tried so far?

Comment: I am looking for CSv output something like: 1,7,2,0 /1, -7,-2,0 / 1, 7,2,0. / specify here as next row in csv file. Till now I have written code : 
i=1
First_value=`ps -ef |awk "NR==$i{print ;exit}" try.csv`
echo $First_value
b=i+1
Second_value=`ps -ef |awk "NR==$b{print ;exit}" try.csv`
echo $Second_value
diff = $Second_value - $First_value 
echo diff
exit... but i dont know how to put this in loop and get the output.. and after putting in variable.. it is not working properly.

Comment: Better to click on **edit** link below your question and provide this information in question.

Comment: Thanks for giving me idea to edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following script (`csvdiff.sh`) will compare two lines of your choosing and output these lines with the original separation characters.

```
#! /bin/bash

# input:   $1 - CVS file
#          $2 - line number of line to subtract from
#          $3 - line number of line to subtract

# Save separators
head -n1 $1 | sed 's/[0-9]\+/\n/g' | head -n-1 | tail -n+2 > .seps

# check for reversed compare
if [ $3 -lt $2 ]
then
    first=$3
    second=$2
    reversed=1
else
    first=$2
    second=$3
    reversed=0
fi

# get requested lines ($2 & $3) from the CVS file as supplied in $1
awk -v first=$2 -v second=$3 -F'[,: ]' 'BEGIN { OFS="\n" } 
   NR==first{ split($0,v) } 
   NR==second{ 
       split($0,w) 
       res=0 
       for (i in w) {
           $i = v[i]-w[i]
       } 
       print
    }' $1 > .vals

# handle reversed compare
if [ $reversed -eq 1 ]
then
    awk '{print $1 * -1}' .vals > .tmp
    mv .tmp .vals
fi

# paste the differences with the original seperation characters
paste -d'\0' .vals .seps | paste -sd'\0'

# remove used files
rm .vals .seps
```

Example usage:

```
$ cat file
2,2,3,4,5:10
1,2,3,4,5:12
$ chmod +x csvdiff.sh
$ bash csvdiff.sh file 1 2
1,0,0,0,0:-2
$ bash csvdiff.sh file 2 1
-1,0,0,0,0:2
```

Note that this script will compare fields separated by several delimiters such as colons and commas. It will, however, not take semantics like time etc. into account. Meaning that dates wont be subtracted as a whole but component-wise.

Comment: Earlier itself I tried accepting it. But my rating is low.:(.. Sorry.. But thank